# Removed tags in output xml having no values in input xml by checking it with xslt

Tags: xml, xslt

I am new to xslt.Tried to remove the tag from result/output xml which has no values for the tag present in input xml.But output xml,tags to be printed are coming multiple times.

**INPUT xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<catalog>
  <cd>
    <title>Empire Burlesque</title>
    <artist>Bob Dylan</artist>
    <country>USA</country>
    <company>Columbia</company>
    <price></price>
    <year>1985</year>
  </cd>
  <cd>
    <title>Hide your heart</title>
    <artist>Bonnie Tyler</artist>
    <country>UK</country>
    <company>CBS Records</company>
    <price>9.90</price>
    <year>1988</year>
  </cd>
  </catalog>
```

**XSLT**

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" 
indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
<xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  <html>
  <body>
    <h2>My CD Collection</h2>
    <table border="1">
      <tr bgcolor="#9acd32">
        <th>Title</th>
        <th>Artist</th>
<th>Price</th>
      </tr>
      <xsl:for-each select="catalog/cd">
      <tr>
        <td><xsl:value-of select="title" /></td>
        <td><xsl:value-of select="artist" /></td>
<td><xsl:value-of select="price" /></td>
      </tr>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </table>
  </body>
  </html>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="price[not(node())]"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**OUTPUT Expected HTML**

Print without `<price></price>` tag that has no value but whats actually being shown as output is multiple values of all the tags
Please help me with this

```
<html>
   <body>
      <h2>My CD Collection</h2>
      <table border="1">
         <tr bgcolor="#9acd32">
            <th>Title</th>
            <th>Artist</th>
            <th>Price</th>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>Empire Burlesque</td>
            <td>Bob Dylan</td>

         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>Hide your heart</td>
            <td>Bonnie Tyler</td>
            <td>9.90</td>
         </tr>
      </table>
   </body>
</html>
```

But what i am getting is that its printed in loop multiple times.

Comment: Can you edit your question to show the output you expect? It is not clear if you want to output HTML, or just amend the XML to remove the `price` tag. Thank you

Comment: I did edit,i need an output xml ,where the tags that had no values in input xml are removed.

Comment: i am able to remove the price tag in output but once it has the complete html tags/body,all the fields are getting printed multiple times.

Comment: If you want to output html, there is no need to "remove" the empty price tag. You would simply not select it when you come to produce the output. But can you please edit your question to show the exact output you want, rather than try to describe what you want. Thank you very much!

Comment: I have edited my question,please let me know if i am still not clear.Thanks,looking forward for your help.

Answer (score 0):

```
add a condition for price tag
<xsl:template match="/">

        <html>
            <body>
                <h2>My CD Collection</h2>
                <table border="1">
                    <tr bgcolor="#9acd32">
                        <th>Title</th>
                        <th>Artist</th>
                        <th>Price</th>
                    </tr>
                    <xsl:for-each select="catalog/cd">
                        <tr>
                            <td><xsl:value-of select="title" /></td>
                            <td><xsl:value-of select="artist" /></td>
                            <xsl:choose>
                                <xsl:when test="price = ''"/>
                                <xsl:otherwise><td><xsl:value-of select="price" /></td></xsl:otherwise>
                            </xsl:choose>

                        </tr>
                    </xsl:for-each>
                </table>
            </body>
        </html>
    </xsl:template>
```

Comment: But that wont remove the entire price tag,it just gives no value,i want the entire tag to be removed in output.Thanks for your response though Imran.

Comment: Please give a sample of output

Comment: i am able to remove the complete price tag in output:-   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<catalog>
   <cd>
      <title>Empire Burlesque</title>
      <artist>Bob Dylan</artist>
      <country>USA</country>
      <company>Columbia</company>
      <price/>
      <year>1985</year>
   </cd>
   <cd>
      <title>Hide your heart</title>
      <artist>Bonnie Tyler</artist>
      <country>UK</country>
      <company>CBS Records</company>
      <price>9.90</price>
      <year>1988</year>
   </cd>
</catalog>

Comment: But if <html> body added,the out put is resluting in :-<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> <catalog> <cd> <title>Empire Burlesque</title> <artist>Bob Dylan</artist> <country>USA</country> <company>Columbia</company> <price/> <year>1985</year> </cd> <cd> <title>Hide your heart</title> <artist>Bonnie Tyler</artist> <country>UK</country> <company>CBS Records</company> <price>9.90</price> <year>1988</year> </cd> </catalog>*(multiple times)

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your script is that you put everyting in a template
matching `@*|node()`.

A template with such matching is usually the *identity template*, used when you create XML output.

But the output of your script is HTML markup, with transformed input
inside (for every `cd` element).

My suggestion is:

- Change `match="@*|node()"` to `match="/"` (your template should match
  only the document node).
- Delete fragment from `<xsl:copy>` to `</xsl:copy>` (inclusive).

### Edit

Another issue is that if you want to get HTML output,
the output method should probably be `html` not `xml`.

Below you have your reworked script, generating XHTML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="html" doctype-public="-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.1//EN"
    doctype-system= "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml11/DTD/xhtml11.dtd"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <html>
      <body>
        <h2>My CD Collection</h2>
        <table border="1">
          <tr bgcolor="#9acd32">
            <th>Title</th>
            <th>Artist</th>
            <th>Price</th>
          </tr>
          <xsl:for-each select="catalog/cd">
            <tr>
              <td><xsl:value-of select="title"/></td>
              <td><xsl:value-of select="artist"/></td>
              <td><xsl:value-of select="price"/></td>
            </tr>
          </xsl:for-each>
        </table>
      </body>
    </html>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

If you need, change both `doctype-...` attributes, according to your needs.

Note that the empty template for `price` is not needed, because:

- the template matching `/` does all the job, without calling `apply-templates`,
- so there is no chance that `price` element could be processed as matched
  by any template.

Comment: okay,so the code i have mentioned gives an html as out put?but the main concern is,html tags are printed in loop.

Comment: the thing is i am not allowed to post the actual code,the same issue is happening with our code.I just need to delete the complete tag but if it has any html tags or etc,its being printed in loop.

Comment: Your script prints HTML in the *identity template*, so it is actually printed multiple times, on processing of each node (element, text and attribute).

Comment: but if we open the same in a browser,the rows and coloums dont match.

Comment: Unrelated: I saw your EDIT on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52327084/how-to-live-stream-python-as-server-android-as-client ... wrong choice. That question is way too broad, and editing doesnt help here. The OP should either rework the question (dramatically), or it should be closed. Such edits are pointless, and the only thing that really helps would be to put in a close request and maybe drop the questioner a comment.